# My metronome Wittner 903304.0 stopped working

Tags: metronomes

I was playing and the suddenly the pendulum went slower, until It stopped. After pushing it (swing), it stopped again a few seconds later. Since that, the metronome doesn's sound at all and the pendulum continues stopping by itself.
The metronome is just 2 weeks! 
Anyone knows what happened?
Thank you very much!

Comment: When I look up your metronome, it looks like a wind-up model. What do you mean by "pushing it"? Did you push it off a table/piano/etc., did you push it a small distance across the table/piano/etc., or did you push a button/lever/etc. on it?

Comment: I mean I pushed the pendulum, I moved it, in order to make the metronome sound again.

Comment: Please forgive this question: have you wound it up again? Is it winding correctly?

Comment: Yes, I wound it up again. And it is not winding correctly, it winds down and does not sound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It must go back to the supplier! Whatever is wrong is not your problem! The wind up mechanism isn't working properly, but as a new item it needs returning!